# Executing c++ code in VS code without script failed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

While Executing the c++ code on VS through command terminal, getting below error. Coupld you please comment on this.

```
PS D:\Test> .\a.exe
Program 'a.exe' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1
+ .\a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\a.exe
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
 
PS D:\Test>
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: there is no such program there. Did you compile your program beforehand? Did it give any errors? Did it produce a binary in that location?

Comment: Hard to know what to add to the error message you've already seen. First you should check whether the file `a.exe` does exist or not (I'm assuming that it doesn't) then you should ask yourself why it might not exist. Can't really help you with that because you've not said very much in your question. But obviously you should look to the command that was supposed to produce that file.

Comment: your question is `compile c++` but you are not compiling

Comment: Nice to see you have updated the question. But the part that is still missing is what you were doing before you tried to run `a.exe`? What have you done that makes you think you should be able to run `a.exe`? That is where the real problem is. Try and think about this from our point of view. We are not looking over your shoulder. We know nothing at all about what you are doing.